# how to maintain a pointer pointing to elements of vector?

Tags: c++11, vector, stl, c++14

```
 vector<int>vec(N,0);
 int* ptr=vec;
```

Can we do this to vector like arrays or we have to have iterators.what I want is to maintain a pointer pointing to elements of array.

Comment: Can't you just hold onto the integer index of the element?

Comment: do u mean int* ptr=vec(0);

Comment: No, I mean if you want to have a "pointer" to the first element, can't you just have: `int ptr = 0; int elem = vec[ptr];`. Afaik, it's not safe to have an actual pointer to inside of a vector, since the vector may reallocate its memory at some point, invalidating the pointer.

Comment: have you checked the documentation? `std::vector` has a `data()` accessor for that specific purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of couple of ways to get a pointer to the elements of a vector.

```
int* p = &(vec[0]);
```

or

```
int* p = vec.data();
```

However, unless you know what you are doing, I don't recommend using pointers to access the elements of a vector. Use iterators to get access to the elements of the vector. There is not much to be gained and much to lose by preferring to use pointers over iterators.